# Why is apt unable to find bitcoin-qt package?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, ppa, bitcoin

When I run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```

I get this:

```
E: Unable to locate package bitcoin-qt.
```

I am writing it completely correctly; is the PPA not updated for 14.04? Why can't I install the program?

Even if I write `apt-cache search bitcoin` it doesn't show up. 
I'm on Lubuntu 14.04 fresh installation.

Comment: Can't make an answer due to just signing up. Are you using 32-bit? If so, the Bitcoin Core build is broken. Try this: http://bitzuma.com/posts/compile-bitcoin-core-from-source-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is apt-get unable to locate bitcoin and bitcoin-qt package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314550/why-is-apt-get-unable-to-locate-bitcoin-and-bitcoin-qt-package)

Comment: @GAD3R based on the timestamps, the question you linked should be flagged as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put: [that repository](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin) doesn't contain `bitcoin-qt`.

I think the default client for Linux is the QT client so you just need:

```
sudo apt-get install bitcoin
```

Additionally, [the 32bit version of this is *currently* failing to build](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/173258018/buildlog_ubuntu-trusty-i386.bitcoin_0.9.1-trusty1_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz). Talk to to repo maintainer to get an idea of the problem.

Comment: same thing for me `Unable to locate package bitcoin`.

Answer (score 1):

#### 16.04 and later

The bitcoin .deb package that was installable by `sudo apt install bitcoin` in Ubuntu 12.04 is not available in Ubuntu 16.04 and later, however there is a bitcoin snap package that can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install bitcoin
```