# Why is apt-get unable to locate bitcoin and bitcoin-qt package?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, ppa, lts, bitcoin

when i run these:

```
sudo apt-get install bitcoin
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```

i get "E: Unable to locate package"
what do i do?

Comment: In case you don't want to use a snap version, an alternative installation procedure is available in Bitcoin website. https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#linux-instructions

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin is not available in the official repositories, and the [Bitcoin PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin) is not maintained anymore. Instead, install the official snap version with the command

```
sudo snap install bitcoin-core
```

Answer (score 2):

An `apt-cache search bitcoin` for example found a number of packages that used the word 'bitcoin' in their name/description etc.. but they didn't find what I suspect you're looking for.

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~/.local$   apt-cache search bitcoin
base58 - base58 encode/decode: command-line interface
bruteforce-wallet - try to find the password of an encrypted wallet file
cgminer - multi-threaded multi-pool Bitcoin miner
golang-github-btcsuite-btcd-btcec-dev - Go library for Elliptic curve cryptography
libbase58-0 - library for Bitcoin's base58 encoding
libbase58-dev - library for Bitcoin's base58 encoding -- development files
libblkmaker-0.1-6 - implementation of getblocktemplate protocol
libblkmaker-0.1-dev - C implementation of getblocktemplate protocol - development files
libencode-base58-perl - module to shorten numbers using a base58 conversion
libsecp256k1-0 - library for EC operations on curve secp256k1
libsecp256k1-dev - library for EC operations on curve secp256k1 - development headers
python3-base58 - base58 encode/decode for Python
python3-bip32utils - Python implementation of Bitcoin hierarchical deterministic wallet
python3-bitcoinlib - Python module with an easy interface to the Bitcoin protocol
python3-btchip - Python library to communicate with BTChip dongle (Python 3)
python3-mnemonic - Implementation of Bitcoin BIP-0039 (Python 3)
python3-stdnum - Python module to handle standardized numbers and codes (Python3 version)
python3-trezor - library for communicating with TREZOR Bitcoin HW wallet (Python 3)
trezor - utilities for communicating with TREZOR Bitcoin HW wallet
```

I then searched using `rmadison` and it detects it as available for an ESM release.

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~/.local$   rmadison bitcoin
 bitcoin | 0.3.24~dfsg-1          | precise/universe         | source
 bitcoin | 0.3.24~dfsg-1ubuntu0.2 | precise-updates/universe | source
```

which could be why you get your package message; ie. it's available for another release but not yours (or mine).

Online tool https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bitcoin&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all shows supported releases, but not the ESM release my terminal search found.

As for solution, refer @Archisman Panigrahi's answer maybe.  This maybe explains why you get the response you did.

Comment: Nice explanation